# Change CSS style using drop down menu in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make a drop down menu that has a bunch of items (Amelia, Cerulean, Cosmo, Cyborg, Flatly, Journal). Each of these items represent a css file. 
When one of them is selected I want my website to take this selected css file and apply it to the website. 
I would like the drop down menu to interact with jquery, meaning when a item is selected jquery takes over and makes a asyn/ajax call to some mvc actionresult. 
By the way I'm using MVC 5. 
I hope someone can help me sketch the initial groundwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this in my application.

[image]

I'm not sure what to tell you though. It's easier when we have an attempted solution to fix.

Here's an overview of how mine works:

- I have created a controller called **SharedController**. The purpose of it is to contain various actions that render common actions. All of the actions are considered [ChildActionOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).
- My **_Layout** uses [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703541(v=vs.118).aspx) to render the action **NavbarPartial** which is in my SharedController.
- More importantly the Navbar partial then uses RenderAction to render the action **ThemeListPartial**. This action is responsible for getting a list of available themes. The list of available themes is determined at applications startup. I've created a *ThemeFinder* class and *ThemeRepository* class that are responsible for finding and storing themes. The ThemeFinder finds themes by expressions that you give it. In a new class called App_Start/ThemeConfig I've given it only one expression - "~/Content/themes/{name}.bootstrap.css". This will find all themes with that naming convention in that location.
- My razor code will take the [ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) and display a [dropdown menu in the navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).
- To get the themes to change my dropdown menu contains an [AJAX link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) to an action called **SaveTheme** in **ThemeController**. This action takes a theme name as a string and tries to save it in a cookie for the user.
- If the theme is found and saved successfully, the action responds with a success message.
- jQuery then changes the theme by finding the associated [link attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) and changing the HREF contents to the new theme. It knows the new theme relative URL because I have it stored in [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/data).

I completed this before I made the switch to [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org/). The one thing I plan to go back and change is to cut out as much (maybe all) jQuery as possible and replace it with better code.